# java.io.NotSerializableException while passing interface through intent.putExtra

Tags: android, serialization, interface, deserialization

Here's my interface that I extended from Serializable:

```
public interface InstaListener extends Serializable {
    void onSuccess(String response);
    void onFailure(int code, String reason);
}
```

Here's how I am passing this Listener between two activities:

```
InstaListener iListener = new InstaListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int code, String reason) {

            }
        };

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Insta.class);
            intent.putExtra("email", email);
            intent.putExtra("phone", phone);
            intent.putExtra("purpose", purpose);
            intent.putExtra("amount", amountstr);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("env", env);
            intent.putExtra("listener", iListener);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Here's how I am receiving the listener in Insta class.

```
instaListener = (InstaListener) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listener");
```

I have searched many posts but nothing explains why I get the error:
java.io.NotSerializableException

Any help?

**Edit**
Posting the exception and stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: instamojo.testapp, PID: 6785
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = instamojo.library.InstamojoPay$1)
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
                                                                     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
                                                                     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
                                                                     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3271)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1691)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4291)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4249)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4603)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4563)
                                                                     at instamojo.library.InstamojoPay.initInstamojo(InstamojoPay.java:61)
                                                                     at instamojo.library.InstamojoPay.start(InstamojoPay.java:34)
                                                                     at instamojo.testapp.MainActivity.callInstamojoPay(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                     at instamojo.testapp.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                                     at instamojo.testapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5669)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22549)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: instamojo.library.InstamojoPay
                                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
                                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
                                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
                                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
                                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
                                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522)
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) 
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
                                                                     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
                                                                     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
                                                                     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3271) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1691) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4291) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4249) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4603) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4563) 
                                                                     at instamojo.library.InstamojoPay.initInstamojo(InstamojoPay.java:61) 
                                                                     at instamojo.library.InstamojoPay.start(InstamojoPay.java:34) 
                                                                     at instamojo.testapp.MainActivity.callInstamojoPay(MainActivity.java:58) 
                                                                     at instamojo.testapp.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:17) 
                                                                     at instamojo.testapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5669) 
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22549) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Post the entire exception and stack trace in your question.

Comment: Edited & added exception and stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method-local implementation of `InstaListener` is an inner class of `instamojo.library.InstamojoPay`, which isn't `Serializable`. You probably don't want it to be Serializable, so the solution is to write your `InstaListener` implementation as a static nested class, instead of a method-local inner class.

Comment: This solved it. Problem: I can't access getApplicationContext() from within the static class. I need to update a UI thread on the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inner class of `instamojo.library.InstamojoPay`, it's not serializable.

To avoid this exception, add `java.io.Serializable` to your inner class or add `transient` keyword to your inner class object declaration

Comment: I did that: public class InstamojoPay implements Serializable - It didn't help

Comment: @user1051505 It did help. You didn't get the same error message. You encountered a different non-Serializable class. However making everything in sight Serializable is not the correct answer.